# make div collapsible when screen size changes with collapse plugin - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, media-queries

I have this code:

```
<input value="+" class="btn btn_continents" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                               data-target="#collapseContinents" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseContinents" /> 
<div id="collapseContinents" class="collapse in" >
Content...                                                                                   
</div>
```

And it is working ok, if someone click on the button the content shows and hides, but the problem comes when I want the collapsible content hides by default when the screen size is smaller

```
#collapseContinents{
     //display: block; 
    .show();
    @media screen and (max-width :@screen-xs-max) {  .
        //display:none;        
        .hidden();           
    }

}
```

When I add that css(I am using less) and the screen is smaller the collapsive plugin doesn't  work anymore. What can I do?. Thank you.

Comment: That's not valid CSS, CSS has a property and value like the ones you commented out in your example `display: block;`.

Comment: I am using less, it is allowed do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with less if you use the collapse plugin because this plugin manage the open/close by adding a `in` class in javascript:

```
// From Boostrap CSS file:
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
```

So you will have conflicts between the plugin and your CSS on small screens.

You can do it in Javascript: detect the size of the screen and add/remove the `in` class:

```
// Add "in" class if window width > 1024px, remove it if <= 1024
$('#collapseContinents').toggleClass('in', $(window).width() > 1024);
```